# How to use GetSuggestedCategories function for Other Than US Site in ebay api

Tags: python-3.x, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I need to get suggested categories for my items. However, when I make a request I get a reply for the US site. How to get it for the UK?

my code:

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection

api = Connection(config_file=&quot;ebay.yaml&quot;, 
domain=&quot;api.ebay.com&quot;, debug=True)

response = api.execute('GetSuggestedCategories', {'Query': 'INTERNAZIONALE 
1999/2000 AWAY FOOTBALL SHIRT MAGLIA JERSEY NIKE'})

for items in reply.dict()['SuggestedCategoryArray']['SuggestedCategory']:
print(items)
```

Response:

```
 {'Category': {'CategoryID': '2887', 'CategoryName': 'Soccer-International 
 Clubs', 'CategoryParentID': ['64482', '24409'], 'CategoryParentName': 
 ['Sports Mem, Cards &amp; Fan Shop', 'Fan Apparel &amp; Souvenirs']}, 
 'PercentItemFound': '89'}

 {'Category': {'CategoryID': '2891', 'CategoryName': 'Soccer-National 
 Teams', 'CategoryParentID': ['64482', '24409'], 'CategoryParentName': 
 ['Sports Mem, Cards &amp; Fan Shop', 'Fan Apparel &amp; Souvenirs']}, 
 'PercentItemFound': '6'}

 {'Category': {'CategoryID': '123490', 'CategoryName': 'Men', 
 'CategoryParentID': ['888', '159049', '20862', '159178', '33485'], 
 'CategoryParentName': ['Sporting Goods', 'Team Sports', 'Soccer',                
 'Clothing, Shoes &amp; Accessories', 'Clothing']}, 'PercentItemFound': 
 '3'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read somewhere ([The SiteID table](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/SiteCodeType.html)) that you have to set up the header with `'X-EBAY-API-SITEID'` in order for it to return the relevant results. The code for UK is 3, so what most likely is the solution to your problem is simply add :

```
siteid: 3
```

to the `ebay.yml` file you use. If you like to manipulate further the headers/see what else can be added to the `ebay.yml` file  you might want to refer to the `build_request_headers` function in the `traing/__init__.py` module.

Hope that solves your issue!

As I tried your code I also noticed that you use `response` to get the result but `reply` in the for loop, typo I guess. Anyway the result I got with adding the `siteid` is:

```
{'Category': {'CategoryID': '112976', 'CategoryName': 'Italian Clubs',
'CategoryParentID': ['64482', '53597', '112972'], 'CategoryParentName':
['Sports Memorabilia', 'Football Shirts', 'Overseas Clubs']}, 'PercentItemFound': '70'}
{'Category': {'CategoryID': '106485', 'CategoryName': 'English Clubs', 
'CategoryParentID': ['64482', '53597'], 'CategoryParentName': 
['Sports Memorabilia', 'Football Shirts']}, 'PercentItemFound': '12'}

{'Category': {'CategoryID': '112992', 'CategoryName': 'Scottish Clubs', 'CategoryParentID': ['64482', '53597'], 
'CategoryParentName': ['Sports Memorabilia', 'Football Shirts']}, 'PercentItemFound': '5'}
.
.
.
```

**EDIT:**
Adding another way of manipulating headers.
As @Fen pointed out, another way of changing the `siteid` in headers is by adding it to the connection class within the script like he did it:

`api = Connection(config_file="ebay.yaml", domain="api.ebay.com", siteid=3, debug=True)`

Comment: Hello, you get a correct response. However, when I add siteid to yaml nothing changes.
I do it like that:

    # Trading API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
    api.ebay.com:
    compatibility: 719
    appid: -Listingt-PRD-3eaa5c961-f0d...
    certid: PRD-eaa5c9617195-1a5b-48a9-a8....
    devid: 418bf355-9def-4aaa-b85c-17c6cb..
    siteid: 3
    token: AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**lMixXA**nY+

Is this correct way?

Comment: @Fen That seems the same as me. The only difference I can see is: `compatibility: 967`. However, this call should not be affected by that. 
What could help is to get the API call with the `debug=True` then if you can post the `headers` from the logs. It should be the 3rd line from the logs.

Comment: thanks for help, managed to get it work adding "siteid" into connection parameter, not into yaml, like this:
api = Connection(config_file="ebay.yaml", domain="api.ebay.com", siteid=3, debug=True)